# How to determine the futures or spot type for get_historical_klines?

Tags: python, binance

Im currently trying to retrieve historical klines from python-binance library and I have no idea on how to determine the futures or spot type for get_historical_klines.could anyone please help me understand this.I want data on futures...
HistoricalKlinesType.SPOT error.
code:
`client=Client(apiKey,apiSec) candles = client.get_historical_klines('BNBUSDT', Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_2HOUR,\ "10 day ago UTC")`

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: **[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** is a **HIGHLY RECOMMENDED** read for anyone new to StackOverflow

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer:

```
from binance.enums import HistoricalKlinesType

client=Client(apiKey,apiSec) candles = client.get_historical_klines('BNBUSDT', Client.KLINE_INTERVAL_2HOUR, "10 day ago UTC",klines_type=HistoricalKlinesType.FUTURES)
```

> .SPOT for spot